# XML - libxml2 returns XML_ERR_GT_REQUIRED when using SAX not DOC

Tags: c, parsing, libxml2

I need to parse huge and large xml data more than 400KB, using libxml2.
As I know, since DOC is not suitable for huge xml data, I'm trying to use SAX handler and xmlParseChunk.

But parsing in the middle of the xml data, xmlParseChunk returns [73] XML_ERR_GT_REQUIRED.

I have been trying using xmlParserCtxtPtr with xmlCreatePushParserCtxt.
I thought it is caused by huge xml data, so that I tried xmlCtxtUseOptions(ctxt, XML_PARSE_HUGE) before xmlParseChunk.

I've also used strlen(chars) instead of sizeof(chars) when xmlParseChunk reads the xml Data.

But Failed.

Thanks to cooldaemon@GitHub(https://gist.github.com/cooldaemon/106870),
I tried almost same with his/her code.

```
int read_xmlfile(FILE *f) {
    char chars[1024];
    int res = fread(chars, 1, 4, f);
    if (res <= 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    xmlSAXHandler SAXHander = make_sax_handler();

    xmlParserCtxtPtr ctxt = xmlCreatePushParserCtxt(
        &SAXHander, NULL, chars, res, NULL
    );

    while ((res = fread(chars, 1, sizeof(chars), f)) > 0) {
        if(xmlParseChunk(ctxt, chars, res, 0)) {
            xmlParserError(ctxt, "xmlParseChunk");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    xmlParseChunk(ctxt, chars, 0, 1);

    xmlFreeParserCtxt(ctxt);
    xmlCleanupParser();
    return 0;
}
```

It parses the xml Data less than 400KB normally.
I suspect xmlParseChunk or something throws error, 'XML_ERR_GT_REQUIRED' because of the xml Data more than 400KB.

Although using xmlCtxtUseOptions(..., XML_PARSE_HUGE), I cannot solve this problem.

Someone please help.

Comment: Looking at the [xmlParserOptions enum](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlParserOption) there is also `XML_PARSE_BIG_LINES`, add that one and report results. Assuming 400MB of xml is generated, you could try split the xml into multiple files and then source them into the same document using XInclude.

Comment: I've already added the option as following `xmlCtxtUseOptions(ctxt, XML_PARSE_HUGE|XML_PARSE_BIG_LINES);` But it results in same. In fact, I'm trying to split the xml into muliple files but I faced a problem xmlParseChunk cannot parse other files due to mismatching the elements between start and end, which returns [76] XML_ERR_TAG_NAME_MISMATCH. XInclude is news to me, could you please show me some links or more to refer?

Comment: Sad face. Sure, [here is how your document uses it](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/07/31/xinclude.html), [here is one example of how to process it](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/io1.c). However depending on what the underlyng problem is (long lines, many lines, large files, other) you may want to process XIncludes in a more clever way.